# Spring React and Sessions.. how to keep session

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have set up my spring to maintain a HTTP session on an object like so:

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class Basket { .. }
```

controller:

```
@PostMapping(path="/basket/addItem/{user}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Basket createBasket(@PathVariable String user, @RequestBody Item item) {
    System.out.println("POSTING..................................");
    return basketService.addItem(user, item);       
}
```

now when i use a REST client, in firefox i can see that the session bean is created and maintained for the duration - multiple calls. I can append to the object. If i try another client, it gets its own session with its own bean. great..

spring logs the following:

```
 Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [269] milliseconds.
```

However im trying to create a basic front end in react, when react makes a request using axios it gets a new bean every time, which means that the session must be ending after each call. IS that correct? or im not tying it to the react application...

Maybe the approach im taking is not correct, maybe i should use a a different approach, Im trying to learn about spring boot, so its a basic project... and right now i want to maintain user session for a cart. so subsequent calls i can append to the object...

Comment: Session is established using a session cooke. Make sure that axios sends the cookie back on eack call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding the following to my controller it all began to work.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000" }, allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true")
```